# Output wp_link_pages as raw url

Tags: posts, images, pagination, navigation, paginate-links

My post content looks like this

```
<img src="http://linktoimage.jpg" alt=""/>
<!--nextpage-->
<img src="http://linktoimage.jpg" alt=""/>
<!--nextpage-->
<img src="http://linktoimage.jpg" alt=""/>
<!--nextpage-->
```

Basically I'm trying to make a web comic book so I have made each image to split onto multiple pages using the `<!--nextpage-->` feature. Now the problem is I want my images to be linked to the next paginated post. I can't use `<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>` to make a hyperlink on the image cause wp_link_pages outputs it as html and I need it as raw url and I don't need prev & next link. I only need a next link on the image.

Is this a way to make my images to be hyperlinked to the next paginated post?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link

Comment: @jgraup next_post_link only links to the next post. Mine is paginated inside a post using the <!--nextpage--> function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the link generated by the `<!--nextpage-->` tag, it just appends `/2` for page 2 `/3` for page 3 and so on. In other words, it adds a query string `page=page_number` to your post link.

So all you have to do is insert an hyperlink to your image with the next page number for that image.

you still need to add the `<!--nextpage-->` tag because that will break your post in multiple pages. If you don't all your images will all appear on each paginated page.

Comment: Is there a template tag that I could use to apply to my template file? instead of me manually linking the images

Comment: Well not really, since your images are on a text editor (the post content) there is no way to get to those images and knowing what is what.  You would need to use some sort of custom post type with relevant taxonomy to link each images together in the order that would make sense to you or maybe make use of custom field on the post but then again that last suggestion would become messy quite rapidly since you would need to provide each image URL, and the order of each of these images so we could programmatically order the output

Comment: actually, there might be a way, but it would involve targeting and updating your links through jQuery.  But I don't think that would be a good approach for your use case.